# Crontab not running ruby script

Tags: ruby, cron

The crontab -l below doesn't seem to run. The script run by hand runs fine. Here is the error i'm seeing

```
Dec  3 20:12:01 dahlia /USR/SBIN/CRON[13912]: (gigawatt) CMD (/bin/sh -c "(export   PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; /home/gigawatt/drbronnersbot/drbronnersbot.rb)")
Dec  3 20:12:01 dahlia /USR/SBIN/CRON[13910]: (CRON) error (grandchild #13912 failed with exit status 1)
```

And here is the crontab:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; /home/gigawatt/drbronnersbot/drbronnersbot.rb)"
```

Permissions are fully open, its executable, i put the env path at the beginning of the file, still no dice.

Comment: if you are using rvm you might need to bootstrap your crontab with

rvm cron setup

Comment: /home/gigawatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby which is at the top of my ruby file as well `#!/home/gigawatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**: I just noticed the user answered his own post, but I'll leave this up in case someone stumbles across here with a similar issue. I've found it's helpful for some.

I've run into this and found that this is the solution for Ruby scripts.

Ruby needs to be executed in a particular environment. RVM handles this by sourcing a ruby environment file for you particular version of ruby that sets all the required environment variables. For example if you have ruby 1.9.3 patch 448, you can look at the environment file that is sourced:

```
cat /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p484

export PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484'
export GEM_PATH='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global'
export IRBRC='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
```

(Note: My installation of rvm was under `/usr/local/..` but yours may be elsewhere. Use `which ruby` to figure out where your ruby is installed)

Here you can see that it's setting the `PATH` and some other important environment variables. When you type `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448`, rvm actually sources this file in the background.

Cron executions are non-interactive sessions, which means they have no "live" user logged-in in front of a session. When you do it manually and run an interactive session, all this is taken care of for you, but for a non-interactive session, it doesn't know what the shell is or where to find the environment path. Maybe someone with more knowledge can provide a technical explanation as to why.

Anyways, to get around that, add this to the top of your crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/home/gigawatt/.bashrc

* * * * * /home/gigawatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby /home/gigawatt/drbronnersbot/drbronnersbot.rb
```

This is telling the non-interactive cron user which shell to use and then telling it to source the `.bashrc` file. What's in the `.bashrc` file? Good question, you should add this line -

```
source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p484
```

(Once again, replace with your own ruby path)
Basically you are manually sourcing the environment file that rvm would have sourced for you. It's a way of getting cron to use a particular gem environment or gemset.

It should work with those two changes.

**Edit2**: On Ubuntu and similar systems, the default `.bashrc` often contains something like

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

As the comment implies, the file *wont run* in a non-interactive/cron session. Anything you add under that line won't be executed.

In that case, either put your `source` command above that line or just use a different file all together, like `~/.cronrc` for example.

Answer (score 9):

I've gotten it working using

`* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby my-ruby-file.rb'`

Comment: Anyone looking, this is the easiest way.

Comment: didn't work for me, i'm using full paths in cron and in my script

Answer (score 4):

This is quite old but thought I'd comment anyway.  RVM creates a wrapper for each version of ruby you install.

run this command replace 2.5.1 with your ruby version

```
rvm env --path 2.5.1
```

this gives you the path to the environment mine is

`/home/username/.rvm/environments/2.5.1`

you want just the rvm path

`/home/username/.rvm/`

take a look at the wrappers directory there should be a wrapper for each version and gemset you have installed. Test your script with the wrapper

```
/home/username/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.5.1/ruby /home/username/scripts/script.rb
```

or if you have a specific gemset

```
/home/username/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.5.1@gemset/ruby /home/username/scripts/script.rb
```

Use this command directly in your crontab

```
* * * * * /home/username/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.5.1/ruby /home/username/scripts/script.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, i was calling two files in my code and it couldn't find those files. I editing the .rb file to include the full path and it works perfectly now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
* * * * * /home/gigawatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby /home/gigawatt/drbronnersbot/drbronnersbot.rb
```

Comment: Try with the full RVM path as above, you didn't say you were using rvm.

Comment: Nope same issue `Dec  4 12:58:01 dahlia /USR/SBIN/CRON[16513]: (gigawatt) CMD (/home/gigawatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby /home/gigawatt/drbronnersbot/drbronnersbot.rb)
Dec  4 12:58:01 dahlia /USR/SBIN/CRON[16512]: (CRON) error (grandchild #16513 failed with exit status 1)`

Comment: Does it work if you paste it just like that in a terminal from the same user that owns that crontab?