# Ruby script in Crontab

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, cron

I know there have already been a million questions about this but I feel that I have read them all.  I think some of it may be my basic understanding of how crontab works as I am not an expert at Linux yet.

I want to run a ruby script daily with crontab.  I have been trying to test it using `01 * * * * ruby /home/testcron.rb` from `crontab -e`.

Just to confirm that I'm doing it right, once I'm in crontab -e, I write out my command, then "WriteOut" and then enter to save, right?  My crontab looks like the below:

```
                                                                      # Edit this
file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).#
                                                                  # For example,
 you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron($#
                                                                  # m h  dom mon
 dow   command

01 * * * * ruby /home/testcron.rb >> /home/testruby 2>&1
```

I'm pretty sure all the weird line breaks are due to me not being able to make gitbash any wider.

Things I've tried:

- `01 * * * * /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
  /home/testcron.rb`
- Defining the Shell and BASH_ENV (I think correctly?) based on this
  question,
  [Crontab not running ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366718/crontab-not-running-ruby-script).
- Logging with this `01 * * * * ruby /home/testcron.rb >>
  /home/testruby 2>&1` but the log never appears so it appears the ruby
  script isn't running.
- I've tried `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` and it gives the below

  Aug 29 07:17:01 aarmora CRON[18387]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
  Aug 29 08:17:01 aarmora CRON[21194]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /
  etc/cron.hourly)
  Aug 29 09:17:01 aarmora CRON[23532]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /
  etc/cron.hourly)
  Aug 29 10:17:01 aarmora CRON[24551]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /
  etc/cron.hourly)
  Aug 29 11:17:01 aarmora CRON[24910]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /
  etc/cron.hourly)
  Aug 29 12:17:01 aarmora CRON[25275]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /
  etc/cron.hourly)
  Aug 29 13:17:01 aarmora CRON[25662]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /
  etc/cron.hourly)
  Aug 29 14:17:01 aarmora CRON[25940]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /
  etc/cron.hourly)
  Aug 29 15:17:01 aarmora CRON[26114]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /
  etc/cron.hourly)
  Aug 29 16:17:01 aarmora CRON[26517]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /
  etc/cron.hourly)
  Aug 29 17:17:01 aarmora CRON[26917]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /
  etc/cron.hourly)
  Aug 29 18:17:01 aarmora CRON[27368]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /
  etc/cron.hourly)

What am I doing wrong?  How can I debug this better?

Comment: You could try adding a job whose *only* purpose is to echo to a file (in `/tmp` to avoid permission problems), and then commenting everything else out. Then you can figure out whether the problem is cron itself or the way that Ruby is being invoked.

Comment: @icktoofay Yes!  This is exactly what I want to do.  How do I do that?

Comment: A line with `* * * * * echo yes > /tmp/is-cron-working` in your crontab should do the trick. Add that line, comment out all the other lines with `#`, save and quit in your editor so `crontab -e` actually changes your crontab, wait one or two minutes and check that `/tmp/is-cron-working` exists and contains the content “yes”.

Comment: @icktoofay That worked!  Using five stars (`* * * * *`) makes it run every minute?  That means that it's the ruby script that's the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, five stars means run every minute. It’s not necessarily the Ruby script itself that’s at fault—it could still be the way Ruby is being invoked (as it looks like you suspected, given all the different ways of invoking Ruby). You could try doing something silly like `* * * * * exec sh -c 'ruby /home/testcron.rb' > /tmp/ruby.cron.log 2>&1`, which should throw all output including errors (even errors coming from trying to spawn Ruby, not to mention errors from the Ruby script itself) into `/tmp/ruby.cron.log`.

Comment: @icktoofay Sure enough!  I'm getting `ruby: not found`.  So is using `01 * * * *` like I was doing incorrect?  Before using the grep was returning anything useful.

Comment: `01 * * * *` looks okay if you want it to run once an hour, although I’d drop the leading zero. I think what you were doing before redirected any standard output or error from Ruby to that file, but since Ruby was never started successfully, the error was from the shell before it got around to redirecting output, and so the error went to cron, which presumably is supposed to email you but sometimes doesn’t if that isn’t configured properly.

Comment: @icktoofay You are a good man.  This led me to what I needed.  Thanks so much!

Comment: take a look at the `whatever` gem, it's just what you need.